# Is there a way to store index of an array and get its value back?

Tags: javascript

here is the task: I am trying to build an anagram finder which receives a given string (simple word) from an input, then check in a dictionary (of 350k words) and then return all the anagrams of that word. Here is where I got so far:

```
const button = document.getElementById("findButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let typedText = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let wordIn = typedText.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").trim();

  let output = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    if (dictionary[i].length === wordIn.length)
      output.push(dictionary[i])
  }
  let sorted = [];
  let result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
    sorted.push(output[i].toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").trim())
    if (wordIn === sorted[i]) {
      result.push(sorted[i])
    }
  }

});
```

With the current approach I get as final output an array with words alphabeticaly sorted i.e.: cat ("act", "act", "act"...) , but I need them as they are in the dictionary. I was thinking if I could store the index of the words in the output array (which already reduces from 350k to only those with same length) and after temporary sort them by their alphabetic value, I could get only those which match and return them as a new array. i.e cat = "cat", "act", "tac".

Comment: `result.push(output[i])`

Comment: Why do you even need the `sorted` array?

Comment: I also don't see why you need `output`. Just loop over `dictionary`, and check both the length and whether it's an anagram before adding to `result`.

Comment: Maybe indexof() method will help you?  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Comment: @Barmar thanks man, you solved my question, the simply result.push(output[i])  solved the question, I just need to figure out why this solve!

Comment: Thanks @Barmar you totally solved my problem, havent thought about pushing the output. About the sorted, I thought It was going to be necessary for comparision between the words, but now that I read the answers, it may have been useless thus a waste of performance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first of all increase your performance by getting the desired result in the first loop itself, thus no requirement of extra array and extra loop saving space and time.

```
const button = document.getElementById("findButton");
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let typedText = document.getElementById("input").value;
  let wordIn = typedText.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").trim();

  let output = []; //it will have your final anagram list
  for (let i = 0; i < dictionary.length; i++) {
    let sortedWord = dictionary[i].toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").trim();
    if (sortedWord === wordIn) {
      output.push(dictionary[i]);
    }
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const
  // Once, at the top of your script:
  normalizeWord = w => w.toLowerCase().split("").sort().join("").trim(),
  dictionary    = ['foo', 'act', 'bar', 'cat', 'example', 'word'],
  sortedDict    = dictionary.map(normalizeWord),
  // In your event handler, or its own named function:
  wordIn        = normalizeWord('tac'),
  result        = dictionary.filter((_, i) => sortedDict[i] === wordIn);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Haven't thought about this approach, I have some issues understanding the methods yet. Thanks for the advice! Tried and worked, will read more about it later!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `result.push(sorted[i])`

You should `result.push(output[i])` instead.

Comment: Thanks man, this was exactly what I needed, I just need to figure out why this happen, but totally solved!